# Is there a function to search in a ArrayList from a position?

Tags: kotlin

I read carefully the `ArrayList` documentation in *Kotlin* and apparently there is no way to search a value in `ArrayList` starting from a pointer. The alternative is write your own function  iterating the right elements in `ArrayList` and testing the condition.

So I've programmed the following code:

```
fun <T> ArrayList<T>.findNext(cond: (T) -> Boolean, p: Int = 0): Int {
    for (i in p..this.lastIndex) 
        if (cond(this[i]))  return i
    return -1
}    

data class Person (
    var name: String,
    var age: Int
)


fun main()  {
    var v = arrayListOf<Person>()
    v.add(Person("Paul", 22))
    v.add(Person("Laura", 24))
    v.add(Person("Paul", 50))
    v.add(Person("Mary", 24))

    println(v.findNext({it.name=="Paul"}))    // 0
    println(v.findNext({it.name=="Paul"}, 1)) // 2
    println(v.findNext({it.name=="Paul"}, 3)) // -1
}
```

Is there something better than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid any intermediate collections:

```
inline fun <T> List<T>.findNext(p: Int = 0, cond: (T) -> Boolean) = 
    listIterator(p).withIndex().asSequence().find { cond(it.value) }?.let { it.index + p }
```

By swapping the arguments you can call it like this:

```
println(v.findNext {it.name=="Paul"})  // 0
println(v.findNext(1) {it.name=="Paul"}) // 2
println(v.findNext(3) {it.name=="Paul"}) // null
```

Comment: Great! Interesting that running 100,000 times this method is twice the speed of [motee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6661776/motee) answer but has half the speed of the code, less elegant but effective, in the question.

Comment: Yes, it still has to allocate the iterator, do method calls, etc. I should have mentioned that your code will be faster.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum Also note both your method and all answers can be marked `inline` to avoid extra allocations and indirection for the `cond` parameter (which will probably need to be `crossinline`): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html

Comment: I'm doing scientific programming, so I use a lot of `inlines`. It's a great `Kotlin` feature. In my question I prefered the plain case because it's not related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
fun main() {
    var v = arrayListOf<Person>()
    v.add(Person("Paul", 22))
    v.add(Person("Laura", 24))
    v.add(Person("Paul", 50))
    v.add(Person("Mary", 24))

    println(v.findNext({ it.name == "Paul" },0))//IndexedValue(index=0, value=Person(name=Paul, age=22))
    println(v.findNext({ it.name == "Paul" },2))//IndexedValue(index=2, value=Person(name=Paul, age=50))
    println(v.findNext({ it.name == "Paul" },3))//null
}

private fun <T> List<T>.findNext(cond: (T) -> Boolean, position: Int): IndexedValue<T>? {

    return withIndex().filter { it.index >= position }.firstOrNull { cond(it.value) }
}
```

Comment: Nice! it can be adapted to return the index:

`private fun <T> List<T>.findProx(cond: (T) -> Boolean, position: Int=0): Int {
    return withIndex().filter { it.index >= position }.firstOrNull { cond(it.value) }?.index
}`

Comment: Yes, `Int?` will be better than `IndexedValue<T>?`

Comment: You can use `dropWhile` instead of `filter` to avoid extra work.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use withIndex and a filter ?

```
    val arrayNames = listOf<String>("Paul", "Ann", "Paul", "Roger","Peter")

    arrayNames.withIndex().filter {
        it.value == "Paul" //value contains the original name
    }.forEach{
         println(it.index) //indext contains the position.
    }
```

this will give you the output 0 and 2

for your case (person object instead of String) you will use

```
    it.value.name == "Paul"
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `withIndex()`.  It can be used with `Data Classes` too. 

`v.withIndex().filter {
        it.value.name== "Paul" //value contains the original name
    }.forEach{
         println(it.index) //indext contains the position.
    }
}`